Checkbox option to display list only works in a non-module SCSS file?
I was working on a simple project and added functionality that does the standard using a label linked to a checkbox, displaying none for both the label and checkbox on a standard view, and then displaying them in a media query of screen and max-width: 600px. For some reason though, when I would go to select the checkbox, the menu would not transition to the right. The linked SCSS file was navbar.module.scss.
React File:
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import "./navbar.scss";
import { faBars } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function Navbar() {
   return (
      <nav>
         <h1>Alex Wilson</h1>
         <label htmlFor="checkbox">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
         </label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ></input>
         <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Resume</li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   )
}

SCSS File:
@use "../../index.scss" as global;

nav {
   color: global.$default-white;
   background-color: global.$default-black;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: global.$extra-large-gap;
   align-items: center;
   letter-spacing: global.$default-letter-spacing;

   h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: global.$large-font-size;
   }

   label {
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 1;
   }

   label,
   input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
   }

   ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      gap: global.$extra-large-gap;

      li {
         cursor: pointer;
      }
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;

      label {
         display: block;
      }

      ul {
         position: fixed;
         top: 5rem;
         width: 100%;
         left: -100%;
         height: 100dvh;
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      #checkbox:checked~ul {
         left: 0;
      }
   }
}

I tried fixing it for a bit, and genuinely couldn't wrap my head around what was going on. Then just because I truly had no other guesses, I changed the SCSS file to navbar.scss. Then it worked just fine no issues. Can someone please explain how that makes sense? Is it something to do with the modularized class naming assigned to elements when you assign class names to a SCSS module? I'm truly lost on what the difference is.

I'm a bit unclear as to what the problem is - is it that the scss file just didn't load at all, or that most of it worked except for the translation of an element?

@AHaworth When I selected the label associated to the checkbox, therefore marking the checkbox as checked, the ul would not translate at all. When I changed the file name from navbar.module.scss to navbar.scss it then worked. So essentially, I'm only addressing the last CSS selection in the bottom of the media query #check:checked~ul{}. No code change was made, just changing the file from a module to a non-module. My question is why is this the case that just changing the file from a module to a non module made it work?
